# Debugging with monodevelop and unity crash at start

Tags: unity-game-engine, monodevelop

So I'm trying to start debuging with monodevelop and unity. If I understand right first step is to open monodevelop with class u want to debug and hit Run->Run with->Unity debuger. However when i do so, I get 2 errors and it doesn't work. The errors are somehow connected to Debug console class. They are:

```
 Error CS0188: The 'this' object cannot be used before all of its fields are assigned to (CS0188) (Assembly-CSharp-firstpass)

 Error CS0843: Backing field for automatically implemented property 'DebugConsole.Message.color' must be fully assigned before control is returned to the caller. Consider calling the default constructor from a constructor initializer. (CS0843) (Assembly-CSharp-firstpass)
```

These happens in that constructor of DebugConsole class:

```
  public Message(object messageObject, MessageType messageType, Color displayColor) {
  this.text = messageObject == null ? "<null>" : messageObject.ToString();

  this.formatted = string.Empty;
  this.type = messageType;
  this.color = displayColor;
}
```

First error is in last line and second in first line of constructor.

What can i do?
Btw. when i run from unity it works fine, no errors.

Comment: What is this "Debug console class" you're referring to?

Comment: Well I asume that's default class for debuging in Unity. It allows to write debug logs to console.

Comment: You mean Debug.Log and the like? It sounds to me like you're using an external script.

Comment: Well i'm not totaly sure but that script was in project when i started working on. My team newer even tried debuging...

Comment: Is it this perhaps? https://gist.github.com/darktable/1412228 If you want us to help you, that would be relevant info.

Comment: Yes it's exactly the same class as that. And the problem is in constructor on line 311.

Comment: Okay, I'll have a look later tonight if nobody answers this before that.

Comment: Unfortunately I have not been able to reproduce the problem you're having. It might be something particular to your scene setup.

Comment: So is there any way i can help somebody get any idea? I don't need it too much but would be usefull.

Comment: If you could create a minimal clean project that demonstrates the exact issue you're facing and link to that, then perhaps someone can have a look at it. The unfortunate think with debugging Unity errors is that in some cases it depends on the scene/project setup.